# Adding new row to DBContext in Entity Framework is overriding last entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**Problem:**

 Every time I add a new record, it overwrites the last record, thus after looping through, always leaves the table with 1 record.

```
List<Accounting_InvoiceCheck> liIC = new List<Accounting_InvoiceCheck>();
foreach (Accounting_Invoice invoice in liInvoices.OrderBy(x => x.EntityID).ThenBy(x => x.VendorID))
{
    Accounting_InvoiceCheck ic = new Accounting_InvoiceCheck();
    ic = invoiceMaster.Check;
    ctxAcct.Accounting_InvoiceCheck.add(ic);
    //ctxAcct.Entry(ic).State = EntityState.Added
}
ctxAcct.SaveChanges()
```

The Above code only takes the last record, so the count is always 1 no matter what. Very frustrating when I see everybody else's code online doing just that.

**Synopsis**

I am using Entity Framework 6 in an MVC5 application. So I have 2 tables that are being updated when I call a method. The table names are Invoices and InvoiceChecks. The relation is, Invoices is the main table, and when you pay an invoice, you create a record in InvoiceChecks.

Below the code is trying to add it in 2 ways (both are there for your purpose to see). One is to create a list of InvoiceChecks, then call ctx.AddRange(liIC) which leaves the table with only the last item in liIC. Another way I've tried is looping through and calling ctx.entry(ic).state = EntityState.Added which is overriding the last row every time it is called.

Any ideas as to why, no matter how I add, the last row is always overwritten?

```
List<Accounting_InvoiceCheck> liIC = new List<Accounting_InvoiceCheck>();
foreach (Accounting_Invoice invoice in liInvoices.OrderBy(x => x.EntityID).ThenBy(x => x.VendorID))
{
    Accounting_InvoiceCheck ic = new Accounting_InvoiceCheck();
    ic = invoiceMaster.Check;


    ic.InvoiceID = invoice.ID;

    var sumAmt = ctx.Accounting_InvoiceChecks.Where(x => x.InvoiceID == invoice.ID).GroupBy(x => x.InvoiceID).Select(x => new { TransAmt = x.Sum(s => s.CKAmt) });
    decimal amt = 0;
    if (sumAmt.ToList().Count > 0)
    {
        amt = sumAmt.FirstOrDefault().TransAmt;
    }
    amt += invoice.AmtPaying;

    ctx.Entry(invoice).Entity.AmtPaying = ic.TransAmt - amt;
    ctx.Entry(invoice).State = EntityState.Modified;
    ctx.Entry(ic).State = EntityState.Added;
    //ctx.Accounting_InvoiceChecks.Add(ic);
    //liIC.Add(ic);
}
ctx.Accounting_InvoiceChecks.AddRange(liIC);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

**Updated:**
So I discovered that the below code adds it correctly. However, my question is why does the below code work and `ic = new Accounting_InvoiceCheck()` at the beginning of the foreach loop not work?

```
ctxAcct.Accounting_InvoiceChecks.Add(new Accounting_InvoiceCheck()
{
    InvoiceID = ic.InvoiceID,
    AcctPeriod = ic.AcctPeriod,
    BankID = ic.BankID,
    CheckDate = ic.CheckDate,
    CheckNo = ic.CheckNo,
    CKAmt = ic.CKAmt,
    Description = ic.Description,
    TransAmt = ic.TransAmt,
    VendorID = ic.VendorID
});
```

Comment: where is your SaveChanges()?

Comment: `Accounting_InvoiceCheck ic = new Accounting_InvoiceCheck(); ic = invoiceMaster.Check;` Can `invoiceMaster.Check` return the same object?

Comment: Sorry @FatGiant, It's there I just forgot to add it.
InvoiceMaster.Check is the object that is passed from the view in MVC. So on the View, the user fills out some fields, and invoiceMaster.Check is the variable that houses those fields from the view.

Comment: Try swapping the Entry...State lines so that you set the ic state to added before setting the invoice state to modified.

Comment: @danludwig it didn't work. I do know that if it isn't in that order, the invoice updated info is lost. It's like the context isn't able to remember it's state.

That said, I just found out that this works.  Any idea why this works and the way I have it does not? Anyway to shorten it?

`ctxAcct.Accounting_InvoiceChecks.Add(new Accounting_InvoiceCheck() { InvoiceID = ic.InvoiceID, AcctPeriod = ic.AcctPeriod, BankID = ic.BankID, CheckDate = ic.CheckDate, CheckNo = ic.CheckNo, CKAmt = ic.CKAmt, Description = ic.Description, TransAmt = ic.TransAmt, VendorID = ic.VendorID });`

Comment: @Godrules500 update your question instead of putting the working code in a comment.

Comment: @danludwig My apoilogies. I wasn't sure if it should go there since I was curious as to why it works. I'll add it. Thanks.